# How to show/hide a series of ordered elements by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, show

In a series of elements ordered by id numbers as

```
<div id="test-1">
<div id="test-2">
<div id="test-3">
<div id="test-4">
<div id="test-5">
```

Imagine that we want to show/hide each element by arrow keys. What is the best way to do so in pure JavaScript?

The question is when the first three elements are shown, how we can detect that back arrow show hide element `#3` and forward arrow should show element `#4`?

Comment: Did you need to show only one element at a given time or a set of them?

Comment: The current working example is based one one example, but it would be better to have the possibility to show multiple, though, it should not be difficult. Just keep the displayed one visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to keep track of the current div being shown and handle the `keydown` event to check for the left and right keys. See my example below.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/WDQgH/)

**JavaScript**

```
var numDivs = 5;

var divs = [];
for (var i = 1; i < numDivs + 1; i++)
    divs.push(document.getElementById('test-' + i));

var current = 0;
showDiv(current);

window.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
        // Left
        current--;
        if (current < 0)
            current = numDivs - 1; // wrap around back to max
        showDiv(current);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        // Right
        current++;
        if (current == numDivs)
            current = 0; // wrap around back to 0
        showDiv(current);
    }
};

// Hide all divs except for index passed in
function showDiv(div) {
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = div == i ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F00;
    display:none;

    line-height:100px;
    font-size:4em;
    text-align:center;
}
div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#0F0;
}
```

### Update

If you weren't aware of the number of elements then I suggest you use a class to define the elements.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="slide"></div>
```

**JS**

All the javascript would be the same except for how you initialise `divs` and `numDivs`.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
var numDivs = divs.length;
```

Comment: just a question. Do you have any idea to do this without having the number of elements? The only possible way to my mind is to use a parent and count children.